# How RichEdit can accept file drag & dropping in BCB or Delphi program?

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I'm writing a program that could drag and drop text files onto the form to show and edit it by RichEdit.

I've used ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx to make sure that WM_DROPFILES and WM_COPYDATA can received by my Main Form:

```
  ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx(Handle, WM_DROPFILES, MSGFLT_ADD, NULL);
  ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx(Handle, WM_COPYDATA, MSGFLT_ADD, NULL);
  ChangeWindowMessageFilter(73 , MSGFLT_ADD);
```

and call `DragAcceptFiles(Handle, true)` in the form creation function.

Now the drag operation is valid on any places of the window but except the RichEdit, the cursor shows a deny icon when dragging on the RichEdit.

Dragging on any components, eg. text editors, panels, combo boxes and buttons, on the form can lead to receive the WM_DROPFILES message, but except RichEdit.

Actually, I'm sure that it is possible to drag files on the RichEdit because I have wrote the code last year, but I have lost the source code and forgot it. I'm trying to rebuild the same one now.

Here is [the google drive download link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_ybZmLBPLZcb18tXzVkckNtREU/view) to the executable file that I have finished last year. And here is the [github url](https://github.com/zackjtl/SecureEditor) to the uncompleted source code that I'm writing currently.

Thank you for your watching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why `TRichEdit` does not receive `WM_DROPFILES` when using a message map, but you could handle the `WindowProc` of the `TRichEdit`.

A possilble implementation could look like this:

- Drop a `TRichEdit` on your Form
- Modify header file

  ```
  private:    
  TWndMethod OldWindowProc;
  void __fastcall NewWindowProc(TMessage& Msg);
  ```
- Add implementation

  ```
  __fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
  : TForm(Owner)
  {
      OldWindowProc = RichEdit1->WindowProc;
      RichEdit1->WindowProc = NewWindowProc;
      DragAcceptFiles(RichEdit1->Handle, true);
  }    

  void __fastcall TForm1::NewWindowProc(TMessage& Msg)
  {
      switch (Msg.Msg) {
          case WM_DROPFILES:
          {
              HDROP DropH = (HDROP)Msg.WParam;
              int droppedFileCount = DragQueryFile(DropH, 0xFFFFFFFF, NULL, 0);
              TStringList* Buffer = new TStringList();
              for (int i = 0; i < droppedFileCount; i++) {
                  int fileNameLength = DragQueryFile(DropH, i, NULL, 0);
                  String FileName;
                  FileName.SetLength(fileNameLength);
                  DragQueryFile(DropH, i, FileName.w_str(), fileNameLength + 1);
                  Buffer->LoadFromFile(FileName);
                  RichEdit1->Lines->AddStrings(Buffer);
                  RichEdit1->Lines->Add("");
              }
              delete Buffer;
              DragFinish(DropH);
              Msg.Result = 0;
              break;
          }
          case CM_RECREATEWND:
              DragAcceptFiles(RichEdit1->Handle, true);
              break;
      default:;
      }
      OldWindowProc(Msg);
  }
  ```

Comment: If you register a VCL window with `DragAcceptFiles()` (or `RegisterDragDrop()`, for that matter), you MUST process window recreations so you can re-register new windows each time a recreation occurs. In the example above, that means `NewWindowProc()` needs to handle the `CM_RECREATEWND` message. A better solution is to derive a new class from `TRichEdit` and override the virtual `CreateWnd()` method (you can do the same thing in a `TForm`).  Also, calling `RichEdit1->Lines->LoadFromFile()` in a loop is useless, since only the last file loaded will be seen in the UI. So get rid of the loop.

Comment: Thank your for answering. I thought I have found some reason. That's just related to the administrator access right. 

For the program with`DragAcceptFiles()` in the main form initialization, opened by the normal user can drag files icon anywhere on the window to trigger file drop message, no matter what kind of child components you drag & dropped on.  

But when using the administrator account to open the program, drag and drop are prohibited at some components' location (eg. RichEdit, TabSheets of a PageControl).This is my observation, but there may be a better explanation.

Comment: I didn't thought about this aspect so I hope the example is correct now. I left the loop because it nicely shows how to access multiple files if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful example.